# Find number of non-unique column values within a group where a second column value is all the same

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables.

```
Table 1:
id_a, 
id_b, 
id_t
```

```
Table 2: 
id_t, 
name
```

If Table 2 name starts with `a`, I need to find out of anything
with matching `id_ts` also have matching `id_as`.
If Table 2 name starts with `b`, I need to find out of any row
with matching id_ts also have matching `id_bs`.

I need to know how many times these matches occur.

Table 1

| id_a | id_b | id_t |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 123 |
| 1 | 0 | 123 |
| 2 | 0 | 123 |
| 0 | 4 | 456 |
| 0 | 4 | 456 |
| 0 | 5 | 456 |
| 0 | 5 | 456 |
| 0 | 5 | 456 |
| 0 | 6 | 456 |
| 0 | 7 | 456 |

Table 2

| id_t | name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | aaq |
| 456 | bws |

So in this example, I want to see a result like

| id_t | name | num_non_unique |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aaq | 1 |
| 456 | bws | 2 |

My current code is this:

```
SELECT
    t2.id_t, t2.name, count(t1.*) AS num_non_unique
FROM
    Table 2 AS t2
    JOIN Table 1 as t1 ON t2.id_t = t1.id_t
WHERE
        (t2.name like 'a%' and t1.id_a in (SELECT id_a FROM t1 GROUP BY id_a, id_t HAVING count(*) > 1))
    OR  (t2.name like 'b%' AND t1.id_b IN (SELECT id_b FROM t1 GROUP BY id_b, id_t HAVING count(*) > 1))
GROUP BY t1.name, t1.id_t
```

This doesn't currently give me the results I want.
With this code I seem to get the count of all available rows for id_b, and 1 + non_uniques for id_a (so with one non-unique, the value is 2, otherwise the column has a 1).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you explain your output. how come it is `1` for id_ts 123 amd `2` for id_ts `456`

Comment: Because for id_t 123 there is one value that is repeated in id_a, and for id_t 456, there are two values that repeat in id_b.

Comment: Already added the answer for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
select name,id_ts,sum(count_) "num_non_unique" from 
(
select t1.id_a,t1.id_b,t1.id_ts,t2.name, count(*) "count_"
from tab1 t1 
inner join tab2 t2 on t1.id_ts=t2.id_t
group by 1,2,3,4
having count(*)=1
)tab
group by 1,2
```

Explanation:
As you have mentioned in your question that one column value will always be same based of name starting character. So no need to check the starting of the name in your query.

Simply we will check the count of unique row and filter it by using condition `having count(*)=1`.

After getting the unique row simply group it to get the count of rows group by `name` and `id_ts`

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d5be27673a6b797e25503e6d3e428872)

Answer (score 0):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table table_1(id_a int, id_b int, id_t int);
 insert into table_1 values(1,  0,  123);
 insert into table_1 values(1,  0,  123);
 insert into table_1 values(2,  0,  123);
 insert into table_1 values(0,  4,  456);
 insert into table_1 values(0,  4,  456);
 insert into table_1 values(0,  5,  456);
 insert into table_1 values(0,  5,  456);
 insert into table_1 values(0,  5,  456);
 insert into table_1 values(0,  6,  456);
 insert into table_1 values(0,  7,  456);
 
 create table table_2 (id_t int,    name varchar(50));
 insert into table_2 values(123,    'aaq');
 insert into table_2 values(456,    'bws');
```

Query:

```
 with case1 as 
 (
   select id_t, id_a
   from table_1
   group by id_t, id_a
   having count(*)=1
 ),
 case2 as
 (
   select id_t,id_b
   from table_1
   group by id_t,id_b
   having count(*)=1
 )
 select id_t,name, 
 (case when t2.name like 'a%' then (select count(*)  from case1 where case1.id_t=t2.id_t) when t2.name like 'b%' then (select count(*) from  case2 where case2.id_t=t2.id_t) end)num_non_unique
 from table_2 as t2
```

Output:

| id_t | name | num_non_unique |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aaq | 1 |
| 456 | bws | 2 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=60b38b86b874f2e144088602e3ad2287)*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the count -- for each row in `table_2` -- of the corresponding rows in `table_1` where `id_b` only appears once.

One method is:

```
select t2.*, coalesce(cnt, 0)
from table_2 t2 left join
     (select id_a, count(*) as cnt
      from (select id_a, id_b
            from table_1
            group by id_a, id_b
            having count(*) = 1
           ) t1
      group by id_a
     ) t1
     on t1.id_a = t2.id_a;
```